# Are There Azure AD App Perms Available for Microsoft Teams REST API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to start doing some development with the preview edition of the [Microsoft Teams APIs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/teams_api_overview).

I currently have a solution working using the Azure AD v2 Endpoint but I wanted to get a working solution using the v1 Endpoint.

I can't find any Microsoft Teams permissions available in the Azure AD portal and I didn't see anything specifically about this in the [Known Issues](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues) the Teams API.

Can anyone comment on whether there are any options for a pure v1 Endpoint solution using application registration available right now?  If not, is it planned?

Comment: The Teams will be created on top of Office 365 Groups. You can use Groups permissions for Teams. Please let us know if you have specific scenario. Please follow the link (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/team_put_teams) for more info on permissions

Comment: Thanks Srinivas, but can you be more specific?  In an AAD v1 app registration I've tried Microsoft Graph as the API and Read All Groups as the delegated permission, but I get an Access Denied every time I try using the access token I get from it with the Groups endpoint described in the API.  I can get it to work with the same creds when I use the AAD v2 endpoint so I'm try to reconcile these two if possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The v1 Endpoint uses the same permissions as the v2 Endpoint. The primary difference between the two is that v2 scopes can by dynamically requested during authentication while v1 Endpoint requires permissions to be pre-defined within the registration.

When using the Azure Portal, all of the permissions for Teams show up under "Microsoft Graph". For the Teams you'll generally need `User.Read` and `Group.ReadWrite.All`. The Azure Portal lists permissions by description (although you *can* see the underlying scope name in the tooltip):

- Sign in and read user profile (`user.read`)
- Read and write all groups (`Group.ReadWrite.All`)

Note that `Group.ReadWrite.All` does require Admin Consent. Before you can authenticate normal user's, you will first need to have an Administrator go through the [Admin Consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent) process.

Comment: Okay, thanks Marc.  I do have User.Read (added by default for all new aad v1 apps), but I've been using Read All Groups.  I'll try Read and Write all groups and see if that makes a difference.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as the answer, because I'm pretty certain this will trip up other developers out there.  Up to this point, when getting an access token for AAD v1 apps that use Microsoft Graph, you use "https://graph.windows.net" as the Resource ID.  The interwebs are replete with this example, and I have it in my own code that I use for OneNote and other services.

Now with the Graph endpoint for connecting to Teams (and probably other things), the Resource ID you need to use is "https://graph.microsoft.com".  Just ran through a quick test using an AAD v1 app with the Microsoft Graph API and Read All Groups permission.  I'm sure there's an explanation out there from some MSFT person that might make sense, but I have not found it after many hours of searching the web.

Hope this helps someone.